Error: The JVM used for this installer seems to have been installed in a unsecured location
I have two servers

one server can install my application
the other cannot and throws a "Security Error" as follows

Error: The JVM used for this installer seems to have been installed in a unsecured location (non-admin user folder). Installer would now exit.
[Error](https://i.sstatic.net/v86k0gEo.jpg)
[Java install locations](https://i.sstatic.net/mLurRj7D.jpg)
[The only suggestion I have seen on google](https://i.sstatic.net/TpQRlimJ.jpg)

I am admin on both servers and our server team has confirmed that nothing permission wise is different.
Any assistance you could provide would be appreciated.

Removed Java and installed a higher version
Checked folder security permissions

